# Template function called from base class

Tags: c++

I have the following problem.

I have class C which has a template function f3 defined as below.

```
template <class T>
void C::f3(T *obj)
{
 //.......some code...

  obj->f1();

}
```

I have two classes D1 and D2.
D1 has a funcion D1::f1 and D2 has a function D2::f1. These are not polymorphic(not virtual functions.).
D1 and D2 are derived from class B which contains a common function B::f2.

```
void B::f2(C *obj)
{
//..........some code......
C->f3(this);
}

void D1::f2(C *obj)
{
   B::f2(obj);
}


void D2::f2(C *obj)
{
   B::f2(obj);
}
```

As I mentioned, f1 is not polymorphic.

Now suppose we have  the following code.

```
void myFunction(C *obj)
{
D1 *d1 = new D1();
d1->f2(obj);

/*The following is the call sequence.
D1::f2
B::f2
C::f3  //template function instatiated is C::f3(B *), whereas required is C::f3(D1*)
B::f1 //desired call D1::f1
}
```

Is there a clean way of instantiating C::f3(D1*) above.
One way is to copy the code of B::f2 into D1::f2. But I want to avoid duplicating the code.
The other solution is using polymorphism, but then in that case using template instantiation does not serve the purpose.

Comment: Might be one for the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

Comment: I had a hard time understanding this unformatted and poorly named code. Next time make a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), even with an error of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Bathsheba,  Yes, curiously recurring template pattern is the one, I was looking for.